# WooCommerce Shop page : Customize sorting dropdown to product categories dropdown

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to modify the products sorting on the shop page to product categories filter where the user can select the browse the products of categories from there.

I am a rookie in programming. I checked the WooCommerce directory to find the .php file I should work on. I got some clue it is in archive-product.php but I don't see the code which display the sorting dropdown.

Can anyone give me some clue to achieve this ? Or is there any workaround ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution few days ago. I use the function of WooCommerce product categories widget on the shop page.

This line of code will output the dropdown of product categories:

```
<?php the_widget( 'WC_Widget_Product_Categories', 'dropdown=1' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I added this in **functions.php** :

```html
// remove default sorting dropdown
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 30 );

// now add the new dropdown
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'add_product_category_dropdown' );
function add_product_category_dropdown(){
 print '<span class="woocommerce-ordering">'; // So it takes the same position as the default dropdown 
 the_widget( 'WC_Widget_Product_Categories', 'dropdown=1' );
 print '</span>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you wouldn't see the code is that majority of what is generated by Woocommerce is handled by actions and hooks. In easier terms this means Woocommerce creates functions that spits out content and assigns them to different areas of the website.(For more information on Woocommerce actions and hooks, read here - https://docs.woothemes.com/document/introduction-to-hooks-actions-and-filters/ )

I'd recommend using the plugin below. It does exactly what you seem to be asking for and you can avoid having to play in parts you might not be comfortable with yet.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-ajax-navigation/

Most awesome thing is that it's not one of those plugins that force you to get premium to actually get the desired effect.